# where to download opencv-2.4.6.1-android-arm.jar, and ffmpeg-2.0.1-android-arm.jar

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/#Quick_Start_for_OpenCV_and_FFmpeg

I am trying to configure openCV in Android.
The above link asked to download **opencv-2.4.6.1-android-arm.jar, and ffmpeg-2.0.1-android-arm.jar**

But I couldn;t find these jars anywhere,
Where can i download them.

The entire statement says-

- Extract all the *.so files from javacv-android-arm.jar,
     opencv-2.4.6.1-android-arm.jar, and ffmpeg-2.0.1-android-arm.jar
     directly into the newly created "libs/armeabi" folder, without
     creating any of the subdirectories found in the JAR files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list) is where you can find your jars. Download the javacv-bin package and see if your needed jars are present there.

Then if you have installed opencv properly in your system you need to add the required libraries to the project.

If you are using a windows system you can check [this](http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/2012/04/javacv-setup-with-eclipse-on-windows-7.html) link.

If you are using ubuntu or linux systems then you need to add the path of the lib file to the Native Library location, which is normally inside the opencv/release/lib folder.

I have already told you where to get the libraries from. If you want to see the installation process for ubuntu, here is the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation).

I hope this helps..For further queries please do comment, i will try and help to the best of my knowledge..cheers :)

Comment: I've already installed openCV in my system and developed application in java as well .. But now I am trying to do it for android. and there I am stuck.Can you elaborate exactly how to configure android for openCV , I want to develop an app in android. I got javaCv different link and then openCV manager link .. confused totally

Comment: The link i gave you for the jars is the zip file which has all the jar files including your android-arm.jar. Put this jar into your project and link it to the corresponding library folder where you have your opencv. Here is a link which might help you..http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html.

Answer (score 0):

Above reply to my query was perfect, Here I am just describing it more, if other needs help-

In Windows-7

- Extract all the jar files and collect all the .so files. One ensurity
  is there that no .so files will be repeated in any of the 3 jars, so
  each jar has there own specific sets of .so fiies.
- When you are copying the so to the emntioned named directory , please
  take care the name , it is **armeabi** , a spelling mistake will ruin
  your life.
- Before class path setting , check your **jre version**, The Jre version
  and OpenCV library version must match. Once you sure about jre
  version , then add that in your class path , restart system and enjoy